# Canvas load image before anything starts?

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas

When I play my game and click space I show a pause screen with info and images. However the images dont show for like 5 seconds after the page is loaded. I guess this is because they are still loading. How can I prevent canvas from running until the images are loaded?

http://www.taffatech.com/Snake.html
click space straight away.
then click it again, wait 6-10 seconds and press it again.

this is the code for showing the images:

```
if(level == 1)
{
var img = new Image();
img.src = 'egg.png';
con.drawImage(img,350,40);
}
else if(level ==2)
{
var img = new Image();
img.src = 'baby.png';
con.drawImage(img,350,40);
}

else if(level ==3)
{
var img = new Image();
img.src = 'adult.png';
con.drawImage(img,350,40);
}

else
{
 var img = new Image();
 img.src = 'ultimate.png';
 con.drawImage(img,350,40);
}
```

Comment: Can you show us some code rather than just linking to your site please

Comment: You need to wait for the `load` event of each images to fire (e.g., listening on image `img` with `img.onload` or `img.addEventListener("load", ...)`.

Comment: You could try loading the images with the page load so it gets cached.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to delay the execution of other scripts until the image you desire has been loaded.  In your JavaScript, whenever you want to preload your image, you can use the following code as a guideline:

```
function onImageLoad(e) {
     // Put code here to start your canvas business.
};

var image = new Image();
image.addEventListener('load', onImageLoad);
image.src = 'the/path/to/your/image.whatever'
```

Your onImageLoad function could render your image to the canvas (so the image load happens when you press pause), or you could have this script execute at the beginning and the function simply stores the image into a global variable.  Up to you!

Hope this helps :)

Comment: SO would all my code go inside that function? Even my document .ready function that everything is contained in? How could I wait for all the images?

Comment: That's really up to how you wish to design your application!  I'm sure a quick google of "batch image loader" would yield some great results for delaying execution until ALL images are loaded.  Also, it's up to you whether you want to start your application AFTER all images are loaded, or just load images when need and then draw then on the canvas when they're ready separately.  Hopefully that makes sense!

Comment: @bob Such tools are also called "preloaders" -- a search for "javascript image preloader" will likely turn up useful results as well.

Comment: Thanks guys, I did it and it works, I decided just to load the first image, as nobody will be leveling up before the images have time to load!

Comment: h00ray!  Glad we could help :)

Answer (score 1):

You can keep all the image paths in an array and load all the images before starting

```
var imageObjects = [];

function loadImages(images, onComplete) {

    var loaded = 0;

    function onLoad() {
        loaded++;
        if (loaded == images.length) {
            onComplete();
        }
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
        var img = new Image();
        img.addEventListener("load", onLoad);
        img.src = images[i];
        imageObjects.push(img);
    }
}


function init() {
    alert("start game");
    // use imageObjects which will contain loaded images
}

loadImages(["egg.png", "baby.png", "adult.png", "ultimate.png"], init);
```

Answer (score 0):

waitForImages jQuery plugin

[GitHub repository.](https://github.com/alexanderdickson/waitForImages)

```
$('selector').waitForImages(function() {
    alert('All images are loaded.');
});
```

Comment: This person might not be using jQuery, so this isn't a general solution, unfortunately.. albeit still VERY correct!

Comment: @GrahamRobertson The question is tagged `jquery`, so I assume jQuery answers are fair game. **However**, the plugin referenced here only deals with `<img>` elements in the DOM (*not* `Image` objects in scripts), so this does not answer the question.

Comment: @apsillers!  Ah true!  I did not see that jQuery tag, I just didn't see any jQuery in the code.  Thanks, man! :)  My apologies.